# XML Error when running on MAC Snow Leopard

Tags: xml, macos, perl

Trying to run my xml parsing process on snow-leopard. The process reads in an xml file, parses,extracts chunks of data and writes to an output file.
Process works like a charm on Windows machine.(Thanks to you all at stackoverflow) But when trying to run on my mac, the chunks of text data in the output file are getting written as:

XML::LibXML::Element=SCALAR(0x1008c61d0)|

Did a google search but didnt find anything related. Hoping someone here can point out what the issue is? Could this be install related or process related?

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
simak

Comment: My magic crystal ball says you might have a bug in your code.

Comment: The code runs on the mac. Only a few attributes are being written with that notation. What does this indicate? Will help to debug the code if I know what it means. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of XML::LibXML have string overloading for XML::LibXML::Element objects. So the following script would show different output with different XML::LibXML versions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string(<<EOF);
<test>
  <foo>hello</foo>
</test>
EOF
my($node) = $doc->findnodes('/test/foo');
print $node, "\n";
```

On an old system with XML::LibXML 1.69 installed the output is:

```
XML::LibXML::Element=SCALAR(0x8259700)
```

On a newer system with 2.0014 installed the output is:

```
<foo>hello</foo>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much, Slaven. I installed XML::LibXML from CPan directly on the Mac. Guess it pulled the older version. Any idea how I can specify the version when installing?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with the Mac/Perl issues. It's probably better to stay compatible with older XML::LibXML versions and not rely on the strinigication overload. So just use $xml_element->serialize
to get a XML snippet or $xml_element->textContent if you want the text content inside of an element.